# Как присвоить класс к блоку при загрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript, html

Вкратце - с помощью чего можно задать присвоение класса блоку еще при загрузке страницы на нативном js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью чего? Вы уже ответили себе на этот вопрос - с помощью JS.

Вероятно, вопрос в том, **как**?

Здесь сыграет роль следующая вещь. При загрузке страницы, если вы подразумеваете тот момент, когда она уже получена с сервера, но DOM еще не построен, сделать вы этого не сможете.

Правда, с одной небольшой оговоркой: DOM может быть и не построен, но тот элемент, которому вы хотите добавить класс, присутствовать *обязан*.

Поэтому, скрипт должен выполняться:

а) после полной готовности DOM
б) после готовности необходимого элемента

### Вариант а):

Навесить на документ обработчик события "DOMContentLoaded", выполняющийся тогда, когда DOM построена, после чего добавить блоку класс:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // код навешивания класса приведен ниже в ответе
});
```

Подключать внешний скрипт с атрибутом `defer`, гарантирующим выполнение скрипта по готовности DOM:

```
<script src="script.js" defer>
```

### Вариант б):

Выполнять тело скрипта находится после необходимого элемента:

```
<div>Элемент, которому нужно добавить класс</div>
<script>// Сценарий добавления класса, опять же, приведен ниже</script>
```

Теперь о главном: **как, собственно, добавить элементу класс**?

Сначала находим необходимый элемент любым известным способом: это может быть поиск по id (`document.getElementById`), поиск по CSS-пути (`document.querySelector`), да по чему угодно, даже по классу, если у элемента, которому нужно его добавить, уже есть какой-либо класс. Дальше по ситуации выбираем наиболее подходящее решение:

### Вариант 1:

```
element.className = "класс";
```

Минусы: такой подход полностью перезаписывает текущее значение атрибута `class`. Например, если до выполнения скрипта класс элемента `element` был равен `class1 class2 myclass`, то теперь он будет равен просто `класс` - предыдущие значения будут перезаписаны.

### Вариант 2, "Улучшенный":

```
element.classList.add("Класс");
```

Данный подход *добавит* элементу класс. Предыдущие останутся, если были до этого. Если не было, то `класс` станет единственным классом элемента `element`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
window.onload = () => {
  div.className = 'div';
  console.log(div)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Коллбэк `onload` выполняется тогда, когда все сопутствующие ресурсы страницы подгружены. Обычно нет необходимости ждать этого момента, тем более, что автор уточнил, что "при загрузке страницы", а не после того, как она загружена.

Comment: И вообще этот код, вероятнее всего, не сработает, поскольку поиск элемента производится, скорее всего, еще до того, как страница была загружена. Результатом будет что-то вроде `Could not get className property of undefined`.

Comment: я чего-то не вижу таких подробностей в вопросе....

Comment: "еще при загрузке страницы" - цитата скопирована прямо из вопроса. Из нее следует, что автор, вероятнее всего, хочет, чтобы к тому моменту, как страница полностью готова (`onload`) класс **уже** был добавлен. Хотя это неточно, я ведь не телепат. Но из описанного задания следует именно это.

Answer (score 1):

Если в тот момент, когда загрузился HTML, но не загрузились картинки и фрэймы, то так:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var block = document.getElementById("block");
    block.className += " myClass";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Прочитал ответы, и если я правильно понял, вы хотите наоборот, до загрузки всего контента, чтобы был класс на блоке, тогда вы прям в `html` ставьте данный класс для блока

```
<div class="loaded"></div>
```

а потом на `js`,после загрузки всей страницы, удаляйте данный класс

```
window.onload = function() {
     var div = document.querySelector('.loaded')
     div.classList.remove("loaded");
}
```